# This.state is giving back only 1 item, in console log i see 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rendering, state

I am trying to render my setState objects, but when I render them, I see only 1, but in the console log, I can see both objects are saved.

```
  getUserTeams() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var uid = user.uid;

    uzivateleRef.on("value", snapshot => {
      let dataTeams = snapshot.child("/" + uid + "/teams").val();

      let n = Object.keys(dataTeams).map((key, i) => {
        this._getTeamsAndRoles(
          dataTeams[key].roleID,
          dataTeams[key].teamID,
          uid
        );
      });
    });
  }

  _getTeamsAndRoles = (roleID, teamID, uid) => {
    fireRef.on("value", snapshot => {
      let dataTeams = snapshot.child("roles/teams/" + teamID + "/").val();
      let dataRoles = snapshot.child("roles/role/" + roleID + "/").val();

      let userTeams = (
        <View key={dataTeams.id} style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.textContainerName}>{dataTeams.name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.textContainerName}>{dataRoles.name}</Text>
        </View>
      );
      this.setState({ userTeams });
      console.log(this.state.userTeams);
    });
  };
```

And I need to get both items, not just 1
Here is how I render `setState`

```
    <Text style={styles.h1}>- VAŠE TEAMY -</Text>
    {this.state.userTeams}
    <Button
      type="clear"
      titleStyle={{ color: "#3c59ff" }}
      title="Přidat se do nového teamu"
      onPress={null}
    />
```

This is what am I getting in console.log:

[image]
[image]

Comment: remove your console.log and put it outside firebase.on(), you'll see there. Here you have logged values in loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up the state you can immediately only render anything in the console by this way.

```
this.setState({ 
   // here you set up, what you need 
},()=>{
    console.log(this.state.anything)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`setState` works asynchronously. doing this

```
this.setState({ userTeams });
console.log(this.state.userTeams);
```

won't guarantee you will see the updated value right away. If you want you see the values for some reason one way is as @Newell answered.

Usually, you'd want to know if right data is rendering so `setState` will cause a render whenever it has finished and you can check the value by putting a log in the `render` method. Take a look at this doc:
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

A suggestion, Rendering and storing components with values and continuously update them in state may cause you unnecessary rerenders and it would be harder to **maintain and test**. Instead, make a separate component and make it a controlled component. More details here: 
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components